# associative array inside single php row

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to consult as to how to best do the following:

i have certain primary values which i want to insert into my MySQL db as an array, lets say this are parents.

```
array(parent1,parent2,parent3,parent4);
```

Now, those parents have one or more children each, ex:

```
parent1 => child1,
parent2 => child1,child2,child3,
parent3 => child1, child2, child3
```

ect...

I'm gonna have a form where you add a parent and after this one is added you can add X children to it.

so what would be the best way to handle such a situation, i guess it would require an associative array, could some one please give me an advice, working with php and MySQL.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT can do it in mysql but at least post some same data and schema to let people try

Comment: Don't do it.... otherwise the next quastion you ask will be how to search with matches on partial entries - normalize your database

Comment: what do you mean by normalize?

Comment: Do you ask how to store it in DB or how to handle it in php?

Comment: @durian - suggest you google on database normalization or on "third normal form" to learn a bit about how to structure relational databases (e.g. what the word "relational" means) - just avoid wikipedia, which is dry and theoretical

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array that looks like this:

```php
$arr = array(
    'parent1' => array('child1'),
    'parent2' => array('child1', 'child2'),
    'parent3' => array('child1', 'child2', 'child3')
);
// Debugging...
var_dump(array_keys($arr)); // These are the parents
var_dump(array_values($arr)); // And these are their children
```

Then, to insert:

```php
var_dump('INSERT INTO `parents` (`name`) VALUES ("'.implode('"), ("', array_keys($arr)).'");'); // These are the parents
foreach ($arr as $parent => $children)
    var_dump('INSERT INTO `children` (`parent_name`, `name`) VALUES ("'.$parent.'", "'.implode('"), ("'.$parent.'", "', array_keys($children)).'");'); // These are the children
```

Change `var_dump()` to the corresponding method that you use to run queries.